# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" and NSURL

Tags: ios, nsurl, unrecognized-selector

I got this message in my debug area but it does not block the iPhone simulator:

```
-[__NSCFString _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

and it appears in these lines :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:6]] ;
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:urlString ofType:@"m4a"]];
NSLog(@"object class: %@", [[array objectAtIndex:6] class]);
NSError *error;
_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
          [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    _player.delegate = self;
    [_player prepareToPlay];
}
```

Object 6 of my array is a string "question1" and question1.m4a is an audio file then read with a `AVAudioPlayer` instance.

Any idea from where the problem comes ?

EDIT :
Full error line :

```
2014-07-09 16:23:41.007 TOEIC3[8497:60b] -[__NSCFString _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb42ee40
```

EDIT2 :
Array definition :

```
<array>
    <string>P2.png</string>
    <string>A</string>
    <string>B</string>
    <string>C</string>
    <string>D</string>
    <string>3</string>
    <string>question1</string>
</array>
```

Messages from the debug area:

```
  (lldb) po [array class]
__NSCFArray

(lldb) po [[array objectAtIndex:6] class]
__NSCFString
```

Besides, according to breakpoint, error appears just after this line:

```
    _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
```

And I get this error with a .m4a file but not with the original file in .aiff.
Could it come from a loss of information during the conversion ?

EDIT3:

```
object class urlString: __NSCFString
object class url: NSURL
```

EDIT4(edited) :

[image: Exception stack trace]

The following line is shown as breakpoint 1.1 and highlighted :

```
_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
```

Comment: Double check the object class: NSLog(@"object class: %@", [[array objectAtIndex:6] class]);

Comment: object class: __NSCFString

Comment: Could you show the full error log? usually unrecognized selector crash the application

Comment: It would be good to see the exception stack trace.

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is not in the above statements.

Comment: Please see my edited post. I assumed error were in the above statements because error message disappears when I comment these lines.

Comment: Note that your string in the array is "question1" not "question12", although I don't feel like it's relevant to your issue

Comment: Right. I've just corrected it.

Comment: Can u log the urlString & url class , this kind of issue occurs when a message is sent to an object which had already been released or was improperly allocated.

Comment: It would be good to see the exception stack trace.

Comment: (Are you using try/catch in your code?)

Comment: @HotLicks I don't use try/catch. Please see EDIT4 for the stack trace.

Comment: _appears these lines_... which line exactly? are you using `MRR`?

Comment: @holex Please develop. First time I use stack trace and I don't really get how it works. First of EDIT4 lines corresponds to the above code (`Listening1PracticeViewController`) and others to hundreds of lines like `0x34baac6:  addl   $0x8, %esp` which looks like chinese to me.

Comment: @GoldXApp, and are you using `MRR`?

Comment: You almost certainly have a memory management issue.  Either that or the URL's data was corrupted in a way the audio player didn't guard for.  Unfortunately, it could be anywhere -- not necessarily in the code you show above.  You probably should try a run with "zombies" enabled.

Comment: It happens with some soundtracks but not all. I can't see a common factor for all soundtracks failing.

Answer (score 0):

`unrecognized selector` is often a sign of memory management issues. Either the array, or its 6th element, is pointing to something you did not intend to. This can happen if your objects are not retained correctly - allowing them to be dealloc-ed prematurely. When this happens the memory is released and could be assigned to and occupied by any other object.

You need to verify how `array` is being managed to identify the issue. We could provide a better answer if your updated your question to include the origin of `array` and its contents. It would allow us to analyze how it is being retained/dealloc-ed.

Set a breakpoint at `NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:6]];`, run the app and do the actions to reach this code. When it pauses type `po [array class]` into the debugger window.

That will tell you if you're actually pointing to an NSArray instance, or if that has gone away and something else is now occupying that memory space.

You should also inspect the 6th element: `po [[array objectAtIndex:6] class]` and its value `po [array objectAtIndex:6]` to make sure they have what you expect.

Comment: Please see my EDIT2. Debug area shows the array is a NSCFArray and the string a NSCFString. There are only strings in my array.